# How to grab a frame from a video and then manipulate it and then reassemble the video with it?

Tags: python, c, image, video

Basically I want to know the libraries which can do it, preferably in C or Python.

Comment: You want to decode a frame and then to encode it again?

Comment: Hi newcomer, please have a look at [which topic is actually on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which isn't. Asking for preferred external resource is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of OpenCV, but it may be overkill, depending on what kind of "manipulation" you need. It is c/c++ lib, but also provides python and java wrappers.